# Does Borel-Cantelli lemma imply almost sure convergence or just convergence in probability?

Tags: probability, self-study, convergence

Consider a sequence of independent random variables $U_1$,$U_2$,$...$,$U_n$, uniformly distributed on [0,1] and let $U_{(n)}$$=$max($U_1$,$U_2$,$...$,$U_n$).

(a) As $n$ goes to infinity this maximum converges. To what limit?

My answer: 1

(b) Is this convergence in probability or almost surely?

My answer:

I showed that the probability that $U_{(n)}$ being less than 1 infinitely often is 0 using Borel-Cantelli lemma. What I don't understand is whether or not this shows convergence almost surely which would also imply convergence in probability, or just convergence in probability.

Comment: Can you add a summary of your argument for why the maximum converges to $1$?  Writing down the notation needed to do so may give a hint for what avenues to pursue.

Comment: I said that the probability $U_(n)$ is less than or equal to X where 0<X<1 is less than or equal to $X^n$ since all $U_i$ would need to be less than or equal X.

 If you sum this $X^n$ from $n=1$ to infinity it would be finite and hence $U_(n)$ would not be less than 1 infinity often by Borel-Contelli lemma, meaning it must eventually reach 1 (and hence all subsequent $U_(m)$ m>n) must also be 1.

Comment: Cantelli, not Contelli: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Francesco_Paolo_Cantelli

Comment: You're on the right track, but you'll have to write it out more precisely than that if you want to see the answer.  Try precisely writing down the events $E_n$ you're applying the lemma to, and the event the lemma gives probability bounds on.

Comment: So according to the result we have that as n goes to infinity the probability that $U_(n)$$=$$1$ is 1. I'm looking at the definition of Almost Sure Convergence and it appears to me to be exactly that (Unless I'm mistaken?) which would mean that $U(n)$ does converge almost surely to 1?

Comment: I believe so.  Borel-Cantelli  tells you that the probability of a *limit of events* equals 1.  The limit is inside of the probability sign, so that's almost sure.

Comment: Please add the `[self-study]` tag & read its 
[wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info).

Comment: $P(U_{(n)} < 1) = 1\,\,\forall n$, so Borel-Cantelli doesn't apply, even though the support is a closed set.  Your logic shows that the max will exceed every specified value $<1$ eventually a.s., but you don't care about values $<1$, you care about $1$ itself.